# HTML to Rich Text in Google Sheets (RichTextApp)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using RichTextApp https://github.com/tanaikech/RichTextApp#readme
I've been able to convert HTML to Rich Text however this only works for 1 cell at the time, any idea how I could convert this to loop through every row in my spreadsheet?

```
function convertHTMLToRichText() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###"); // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // 1. Retrieve HTML from a cell.
  var html = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

  // 2. Create Google Document by converting HTML to Google Document as a temporal file.
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(html, MimeType.HTML, "sample.html");
  var tempDocId = Drive.Files.insert(
    { title: "temp", mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS },
    blob
  ).id;

  // 3. Put the value to a cell as the rich text using the method of "DocumentToSpreadsheet".
  var res = RichTextApp.DocumentToSpreadsheet({
    range: sheet.getRange("A2"),
    document: DocumentApp.openById(tempDocId),
  });
  console.log(res);

  // 4. Remove the temporal file.
  DriveApp.getFileById(tempDocId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function html_from_B_to_rich_text_in_D() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('B1:B' + sheet.getLastRow());
  var destination_column = 3; // column D
  var values = range.getValues();
  var html_table = '<table><tr><td>' 
    + values.flat().join('</td></tr><tr><td>')
    + '</td></tr></table>';

  var resource = { requests: [
    { pasteData: { 
      html: true, 
      data: html_table,
      coordinate: { 
        sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(),
        columnIndex: destination_column,
        } 
      }
    }
  ]};
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, ss.getId());

}
```

The code makes a html table from the cells of column B and put it as a rich text into column D via `batchUpdate()`.

To use this script you have to add `Google Sheets API` in Script Editor's Services.

Unfortunately it has quite limited abilities to parse html tags:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Yuri that did what I was after. Unfortunate it can't do tags within tags however its close enough.

Comment: Probably @Tanaike (the author of `RichTextApp`) has a better solution. I don't know to reach him.

Comment: I can add another variant of the code that will take every cell, save it as doc, then import it into the next cell as a rich text (with `RichTextApp`). It will handle (I think) tags inside tags. But it will be slow. It would be okay for several cells, for a couple dozens cells maybe. But not for several hundreds of cells, for sure.